# Newbie Doubts, need some help, please

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-1.4

Been looking for days for this answer...  completely new at Django but reading up on it furiously, though not enough...

I want to build a simple data entry system.  A CharField takes a file name and I display the lines in the file in a select box, allowing for the deletion of lines.  The remaining are saved on submit.

### model.py

```
class Inputmodel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

### views.py

```
from forms import InputForm 
from proj.models import Inputmodel


def ipdb_input_add(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       form = InputForm(request.GET)
       if form.is_valid():
           dlist = []
           if 'filename' in request.GET and request.GET['filename']:
               filename = request.GET['filename']
               listp = open(filename, 'r').read 
               with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
                   myfile = File(f) 
                   for line in myfile: 
                       dlist.append(line) 
               myfile.close

           for d in dlist:
               item = Inputmodel(data=d)
               item.save 

           return render_to_response('base.html', { 'form': form })
```

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from ip_db.models import Inputmodel

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    box      = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                   required=False, 
                   choices=Inputmodel.objects.all().values_list('id', 'ipaddr'),
                   widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
                       'style':'width:200px;height:300px;'
                   }       
               ))
```

This is not a hard task and I fear I am missing a simpler way of doing it.  Any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: you should post this question on http://CodeReview.Stackexchange.com

Comment: did you post this question over there?  please post a link for me

Comment: Don't forget to add "()" in method/functions etc calls. It's important :). And take a look at python 'with' statement docs.

Answer (score 0):

Some points that may help:

1. You  render a form only when the user uses "GET". That way when you open the url you don't see anything.
2. You should use forms.cleaned_data to take the values of the form. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/)
3. if the user tries to upload a file (I didn't quite understood) I would use `docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file:', help_text='')` in the forms.
4. Then to take the file you can use `data_raw=request.FILES['docfile'].read()` in the views
5. Finally, an easier maybe implementation would be to create a first form for selecting the file. After submitting I would initialize a second form with the lines of the file. For initializing a form check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) The second submit would save the data.